# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values' using PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to use the bootstrap_plot() function on a data sample, but run into the following error. I have used the same data arrays to plot histograms using matplotlibs hist() function with no problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/Astrophysics/BootStrapping.py", line 19, in <module>
    bootstrap_plot(C, size=17517, samples=1000, color='grey')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.8.2.dev_eec8a83-py2.7- linux-    i686.egg/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 301, in bootstrap_plot
    data = series.values
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'
```

My Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pyfits
from pandas.tools.plotting import bootstrap_plot

F = '/home/khary/Astrophysics/outfiles/outmag20_2dr_9_658.txt'
#data_cube ,header_data_cube = pyfits.getdata("/home/Astrophysics/SDSS_Counts    /count.dr72bright0.3dlz01r01c06.0.fits",1,header=True)


#load arrays with data 
data=np.loadtxt(F)
C=data[:,3]
#obs_count = data_cube.field(3)

#Bootstrap plot
bootstrap_plot(C, size=17517, samples=1000, color='grey')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas bootstrap_plot expects a Series as first argument.

```
from pandas import Series
bootstrap_plot(Series(C), size=17517, samples=1000, color='grey')
```